# How to properly do "login with facebook" in a vuejs + django rest framework project?

Tags: facebook, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I have a backend project using django rest framework and a front end project using Vuejs, in vue I connect with facebook and get the name and email of a user (I use this component https://madewithvuejs.com/vue-facebook-login-component). 
My question is how do I register this user with my backend, should I call the register api and create a new account with the name and email I got from facebook?.

Thanks